# GCP - storage.Client.from_service_account_json

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm new to Cloud environment, I have a question to solve.
'''storage.Client.from_serive_account_json(xpar_gcpstoragekey)'''
What exactly does the object do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You create a credential based on a JSON object that you have. The JSON is the Service Account key file that you can download on Google Cloud.

Most of the time, you don't need to use service account key file. ADC is enough. I recommend you to have a look to [security and authentification on Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication) to learn more about the concepts.